# Problem randomizing answers in eqexam

Tags: errors, packages

I'm trying to use the eqexam package to randomize answers to multiple choice questions in an exam. The package works without options, but when I include the `allowrandomize` option needed for this feature I get an error. Any suggestions?

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[allowrandomize]{eqexam}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}


\begin{exam}{Exam1}
\begin{problem}
In what year did Columbus sail the ocean blue?
\begin{answers}{2}
    \bChoices[random]
    \Ans0 1st random choice\eAns
    \Ans1\label{eq} 2nd (the correct) random choice\eAns
    \Ans0 3rd random choice\eAns
    \Ans0 4th random choice\eAns
    \Ans0 5th random chioce\eAns
    \eFreeze
    \Ans0 None of these\eAns
    \eChoices
\end{answers}
\end{problem}
\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

The error is ''missing begin document''. Again, works fine without randomization.

Edit: I have added `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}`. This produces the following .log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) (format=pdflatex 2011.7.3)  24 DEC 2012 18:34
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"Fall Final.tex"
(./Fall Final.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
 icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
 lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/Users/ChristopherChudzicki/Library/texmf/tex/latex/eqexam.sty
Package: eqexam 2011/09/17 v3.0m An Exam Construction Package (dps)

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
\XKV@depth=\count87
File: xkeyval.tex 2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2009/06/22 v3.00

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 96.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
\CommentStream=\write3

Excluding comment 'comment')
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count88
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count89
\calc@Bcount=\count90
\calc@Adimen=\dimen104
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen105
\calc@Askip=\skip43
\calc@Bskip=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 76.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 77.
\calc@Ccount=\count91
\calc@Cskip=\skip45
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
Package: pifont 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Pi font support (SPQR) 
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+pzd on input line 63.

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd
File: upzd.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/pzd.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+psy on input line 64.

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd
File: upsy.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/psy.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2003/08/22 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks17
\verbatim@line=\toks18
\verbatim@in@stream=\read1
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty
Package: multicol 2008/12/05 v1.6h multicolumn formatting (FMi)
\c@tracingmulticols=\count92
\mult@box=\box26
\multicol@leftmargin=\dimen106
\c@unbalance=\count93
\c@collectmore=\count94
\doublecol@number=\count95
\multicoltolerance=\count96
\multicolpretolerance=\count97
\full@width=\dimen107
\page@free=\dimen108
\premulticols=\dimen109
\postmulticols=\dimen110
\multicolsep=\skip46
\multicolbaselineskip=\skip47
\partial@page=\box27
\last@line=\box28
\mult@rightbox=\box29
\mult@grightbox=\box30
\mult@gfirstbox=\box31
\mult@firstbox=\box32
\@tempa=\box33
\@tempa=\box34
\@tempa=\box35
\@tempa=\box36
\@tempa=\box37
\@tempa=\box38
\@tempa=\box39
\@tempa=\box40
\@tempa=\box41
\@tempa=\box42
\@tempa=\box43
\@tempa=\box44
\@tempa=\box45
\@tempa=\box46
\@tempa=\box47
\@tempa=\box48
\@tempa=\box49
\c@columnbadness=\count98
\c@finalcolumnbadness=\count99
\last@try=\dimen111
\multicolovershoot=\dimen112
\multicolundershoot=\dimen113
\mult@nat@firstbox=\box50
\colbreak@box=\box51
)
\eqemargin=\skip48
\c@eqpointsofar=\count100
\c@eqpointsthispage=\count101
\c@eq@numparts=\count102
\c@eq@count=\count103
\partNames=\toks19
\eq@tmplengthA=\skip49
\eq@pointbox=\box52
\eq@pointboxtotalheight=\skip50
\eqetmplengtha=\skip51
\eqetmplengthb=\skip52
\eqtemptokena=\toks20
\eqtemptokenb=\toks21

(/Users/ChristopherChudzicki/Library/texmf/tex/latex/eqalone.def
\eq@tmpbox=\box53
\eq@tmpdima=\dimen114
\eqcenterWidget=\dimen115
)
(/Users/ChristopherChudzicki/Library/texmf/tex/latex/eqexam.def
File: eqexam.def 2011/08/30 v6.4m Exerquiz support file for eqexam (dps)
\ex@solns=\write4
\openout4 = `"Fall Final.sol"'.

\eq@xrefdefns=\write5
\openout5 = `"Fall Final_xdefs.cut"'.

\quiz@solns=\write6
\openout6 = `"Fall Final.qsl"'.

\c@eqexno=\count104
\c@@exno=\count105
\c@quizno=\count106
\c@eqpointvalue=\count107
\eq@tmplength=\skip53
\c@eqquestionnoi=\count108
\c@eqquestionnoii=\count109
\c@eqquestionnoiii=\count110
\@eqquestiondepth=\count111
\c@questionno=\count112
\c@partno=\count113
\aboveanswersSkip=\skip54
\eq@tabColCnt=\count114
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 1200.

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 1200.

(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols B
)
\c@markerCnt=\count115
\workareasb=\box54
\eqpanelbox=\box55
\c@panel@cnt=\count116
\panel@write=\write7
\c@backofpage=\count117
)

./Fall Final.tex:3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Ty
```

As far as I can tell, TeX never got around to listing the used files. Without `allowrandomize`, I easily found where the used files were listed in the .log

Comment: Your code works for me with miktex 2.9. Which tex distribution and version you are using?

Comment: Does TeX-Live 2011 64bit answer the question?

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` before the `\begin{document}`. You will get the files used with version in your log file. Please paste those details in the question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Can you `\input random.tex` without any errors? What about `\input aebrandom.def`? The output of `\listfiles` may still be useful even when you do not use the `allowrandomize` option.