# Exam class: Randomising the choices

Tags: exam

Any ideas how to overload the choices environment provided by exam class to obtain randomised choices with option to fix any one of the choices?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This question might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96645/28557

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346260/display-item-list-in-sequential-and-random-without-repetition-order/346285?s=5|12.4957#346285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a `exam` add-on package called `exam-randomizechoices` which can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/jesseopdenbrouw/exam-randomizechoices/src/master/). Note that it is still in test phase. Documentation is provided (see link).

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks! By the way, why \CorrectChoice is mandatory in randomizechoices? Can we easily remove this requirement?

Comment: You can omit `\CorrectChoice` but you will get a warning. And you cannot reference to the correct choice.

Comment: I somehow always get this error, if I haven't used \Correctchoice. Package exam-randomizechoices Error: You need exactly one \CorrectChoice, I found 0 in question 1. \end{randomizechoices}.

Comment: I've done this so that exam writers are warned when they don't have `\CorrectChoice` in the choiceset. You can fix this by commenting line 277 of the `exam-randomizechoices.sty`package.