# Can't use tasks to generate answer keys using xparse

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, xparse, tasks

I tried to compile the following code, which I collect and modify from: [Label an item of a 'randomized enumerate'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467079/label-an-item-of-a-randomized-enumerate) written by @egreg.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathptmx, amssymb}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

%Shuffle Questions
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{randomlist}[1][]
 {
  \keys_set:nn { lucas/randomlist } { #1 }
  \lucas_randomlist:V \BODY
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\answerkey}{}
 {
  \subsubsection*{Answer ~ key}
  \begin{tasks}[label = \arabic*.](10)
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_lucas_randomlist_answers_seq { \task ##1 }
  \end{tasks}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\ans}{}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_lucas_randomlist_answers_seq { \use:c { @currentlabel } }
 }

\keys_define:nn { lucas/randomlist }
 {
  environment .tl_set:N = \l__lucas_randomlist_env_tl,
  seed .code:n = \sys_gset_rand_seed:n { #1 },
 }

\seq_new:N \g_lucas_randomlist_answers_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \lucas_randomlist:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__lucas_randomlist_items_seq { \item } { #1 }
  % discard the empty first item
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__lucas_randomlist_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_shuffle:N \l__lucas_randomlist_items_seq
  \begin{\l__lucas_randomlist_env_tl}
  \item \seq_use:Nn \l__lucas_randomlist_items_seq { \item }
  \end{\l__lucas_randomlist_env_tl}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \lucas_randomlist:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    label = \textbf{Q \arabic*.},
    align = left,
    labelwidth = \parindent, 
    leftmargin = \parindent,
    style = standard
}

\usepackage{tasks}[newest]
\newcommand*\tasklabelformat[1]{\textbf{#1.}}
\settasks{
    item-indent = 2em,
    label-width = 1.5em,
    label-offset = 0.25em,
    label = \Alph*,
    label-format = \tasklabelformat
}

%=========================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{randomlist}[environment=enumerate, seed=1]
\item How many letters in the word ``Tea'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ \ans
        \task $2$
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Hi'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$ \ans
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Cake'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$
        \task $4$. \ans
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Tree'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$
        \task $4$. \ans
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Dog'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ \ans
        \task $2$ 
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``House'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $2$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $5$ \ans
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Tea'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ \ans
        \task $2$
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Hi'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$ \ans
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Cake'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$
        \task $4$. \ans
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Tree'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$
        \task $4$. \ans
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Dog'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ \ans
        \task $2$ 
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``House'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $2$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $5$ \ans
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}
\end{randomlist}
\answerkey
\end{document}
```

It pops the below structure and answer keys are not generated.

```
You've placed (tasks)(tasks) \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_lucas_randomlist_answers_seq
(tasks) {\task ##1} (tasks)(tasks) before the first \task
```

When I replace a corresponding part of the code by:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\answerkey}{}
 {
  \subsubsection*{Answer ~ key}
  \begin{enumerate*}[nosep, label = \arabic*., mode = unboxed]
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_lucas_randomlist_answers_seq {\item \makebox[2cm][l]{##1}}
  \end{enumerate*}
 }
```

It works fine, but two lines of answer keys are not aligned as shown below:
[image]

How to solve that? Any solution is welcomed and I'll be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environments from the `tasks` package need to see their body in order to be able to split the contents at each occurrence of `\task` and build the list according the chosen setup. This means you cannot build it on the fly within `\begin{tasks} ... \end{tasks}`. You need to build the environment body beforehand and then use it.

I suggest to modify the definition of `\answerkey` like this:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \use:nn {nV}

\NewDocumentCommand \answerkey {}
  {
    \subsubsection* {Answer~ key}
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_lucas_randomlist_answers_seq
      { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \task ##1 } }
    \use:nV
      { \begin{tasks}[label = \arabic*](10)}
      \l_tmpa_tl
    \end {tasks}
 }
```

`\use:nn` reads two arguments and puts them in the input stream. The variant `\use:nV` reads the contents of a variable as second argument and uses its contents as argument. Before we only need to build up the body of the `tasks` environment as contents of the variable.

BTW: with a sufficiently up to date `xparse` you can read the body of an environment using the argument type `b` which means you don't need `environ`. I modified the code accordingly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathptmx, amssymb}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

%Shuffle Questions
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment {randomlist} {o+b}
  {
    \IfNoValueF {#1} { \keys_set:nn { lucas/randomlist } {#1} }
    \lucas_randomlist:n {#2}
  }
  {}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \use:nn {nV}

\NewDocumentCommand \answerkey {}
  {
    \subsubsection* {Answer~ key}
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_lucas_randomlist_answers_seq
      { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \task ##1 } }
    \use:nV
      { \begin{tasks}[label = \arabic*](10)}
      \l_tmpa_tl
    \end {tasks}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \ans {}
  {
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_lucas_randomlist_answers_seq
      { \use:c { @currentlabel } }
  }

\keys_define:nn { lucas/randomlist }
  {
    environment .tl_set:N = \l__lucas_randomlist_env_tl,
    seed .code:n = \sys_gset_rand_seed:n { #1 },
  }

\seq_new:N \g_lucas_randomlist_answers_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \lucas_randomlist:n
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__lucas_randomlist_items_seq { \item } {#1}
    % discard the empty first item
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__lucas_randomlist_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_shuffle:N \l__lucas_randomlist_items_seq
    \begin {\l__lucas_randomlist_env_tl}
      \item \seq_use:Nn \l__lucas_randomlist_items_seq { \item }
    \end {\l__lucas_randomlist_env_tl}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    label = \textbf{Q \arabic*.},
    align = left,
    labelwidth = \parindent, 
    leftmargin = \parindent,
    style = standard
}

\usepackage{tasks}[newest]
\newcommand*\tasklabelformat[1]{\textbf{#1.}}
\settasks{
    item-indent = 2em,
    label-width = 1.5em,
    label-offset = 0.25em,
    label = \Alph*,
    label-format = \tasklabelformat
}

%=========================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{randomlist}[environment=enumerate, seed=1]
\item How many letters in the word ``Tea'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ \ans
        \task $2$
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Hi'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$ \ans
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Cake'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$
        \task $4$. \ans
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Tree'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$
        \task $4$. \ans
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Dog'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ \ans
        \task $2$ 
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``House'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $2$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $5$ \ans
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Tea'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ \ans
        \task $2$
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Hi'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$ \ans
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Cake'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$
        \task $4$. \ans
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Tree'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $2$
        \task $4$. \ans
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``Dog'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $1$
        \task $3$ \ans
        \task $2$ 
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}

\item How many letters in the word ``House'' ?
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $2$
        \task $3$ 
        \task $5$ \ans
        \task $4$.
   \end{tasks}
\end{randomlist}
\answerkey
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your quick reply. It works like a charm. I'm so grateful to you @cgnieder, this is the second time you help me out.

Comment: hi @cgnieder again, is there anyway to set the start number inside `randomlist` environment, for example, if I want the number starts at 10?