# Get randomized lists with optionnal seed

Tags: lists, enumerate, random

I want to random some items in an exercise and be able to display the corresponding solutions in the same order.

With `xsim` package such lists are in two different places so I thought about a first list to initialize a seed and the second list to use that seed.

I let you this M(N)WE adapted from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532945/169294).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_randomlist_seq
\int_new:N \l_random_items_int
\NewDocumentEnvironment{randomlist}{ o  +b }
{
    % use a regular expression to split the environment
    % around the \item commands
    \regex_split:nnN { \s*\c{item}\s* } { #2 } \l_randomlist_seq
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_randomlist_seq \l_items_tl % pop empty first item
    \seq_if_empty:NF \l_randomlist_seq {
        \seq_shuffle:N \l_randomlist_seq %% randonly shuffle items
        % the number of items to print is given by the optional #1
        % defaulting to the full list of items
        \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
            \int_set:Nn \l_random_items_int { \seq_count:N \l_randomlist_seq}
        }{
            \int_set:Nn \l_random_items_int { #1 }
        }
        % finally, insert the enumerate environment
        \begin{enumerate}
            \int_do_while:nNnn \l_random_items_int > 0 {
                \seq_pop:NN \l_randomlist_seq \l_tmpa_tl
                \item \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
                \int_decr:N \l_random_items_int% one less item to go
            }
        \end{enumerate}
    }
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    This prints four items, it's the exercise
    \begin{randomlist}[4]   %%Generate seed
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
        \item D
        \item E
    \end{randomlist}
    
    This prints four items it's the solutions of the 
    \begin{randomlist}[4]   %%Set seed to match the exercise seed.
        \item soltn A
        \item Soltn B
        \item Soltn C
        \item Soltn D
        \item Soltn E
    \end{randomlist}

    This prints all items
\begin{randomlist}
    \item soltn A
    \item Soltn B
    \item Soltn C
    \item Soltn D
    \item Soltn E
\end{randomlist}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum :**

I've tried to set the seed with `\sys_gset_rand_seed` the lists are now fixed but don't match each other. i.e. the elements of the exercise part are not in the same order than the solution part with same number of elements.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_randomlist_seq
\int_new:N \l_random_items_int
\sys_gset_rand_seed:n {354}     %%% Despite the seed was set, the lists don't match.
\NewDocumentEnvironment{randomlist}{ o  +b }
{
    % use a regular expression to split the environment
    % around the \item commands
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_randomlist_seq { \item } {#2}
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_randomlist_seq \l_items_tl % pop empty first item
    \seq_if_empty:NF \l_randomlist_seq {
        \seq_shuffle:N \l_randomlist_seq %% randonly shuffle items
        % the number of items to print is given by the optional #1
        % defaulting to the full list of items
        \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
            \int_set:Nn \l_random_items_int { \seq_count:N \l_randomlist_seq}
        }{
            \int_set:Nn \l_random_items_int { #1 }
        }
        % finally, insert the enumerate environment
        \begin{enumerate}
            \int_do_while:nNnn \l_random_items_int > 0 {
                \seq_pop:NN \l_randomlist_seq \l_tmpa_tl
                \item \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
                \int_decr:N \l_random_items_int% one less item to go
            }
        \end{enumerate}
    }
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    This prints four items, it's the exercise
    \begin{randomlist}[4] %%Generate seed
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
        \item D
        \item E
    \end{randomlist}
    
    This prints four items it's the solutions of the 
    \begin{randomlist}[4]   %%Set seed to match the exercise seed.
        \item Soltn A
        \item Soltn B
        \item Soltn C
        \item Soltn D
        \item Soltn E
    \end{randomlist}
    
    This prints all items in a different order than the two previous one
    \begin{randomlist}
        \item Soltn A
        \item Soltn B
        \item Soltn C
        \item Soltn D
        \item Soltn E
    \end{randomlist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't split with `\regex_split:nnN` here, you just want to split at `\item`, use `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_randomlist_seq { \item } {#2}` instead (`\seq_set_split:Nnn` will remove the surrounding spaces for you).

Comment: To set the seed of the RNG use `\sys_gset_rand_seed:n`, to get the current seed use `\sys_rand_seed:`

Comment: Why don't you use a program, that was made for this, including solved problems with uniformity of distribution : R ?

Comment: You might calculate the seed from the list contents, though `expl3` doesn't have the required function built in to get the hash of a token list. But you could write your environment contents into a temporary file and use `\file_mdfive_hash:n` or `\file_get_mdfive_hash:nN` to get that file's hash, then set the seed dependent on it.

Comment: @Skillmon `\str_mdfive_hash:n`?

Comment: @JosephWright ohh, I searched the `l3tl` module... My bad! :)

Comment: @MS-SPO I like to keep things in LaTeX for coherence + I don't know R + I've already all my exercises compatible with LaTeX atm. I'm only looking for a way to random some (1 of 20) exercises.

Comment: @Skillmon I've tested but can't achieved what I'm expecting. With `\sys_gset_rand_seed:n` the lists are fixed but are not the same. See edited question

Comment: @Piroooh, understand. Which exam-package do you use (e.g. link to an earlier question you posted)? May be it's time for R? E.g. `> sample(1:20,5,replace=F)` yields 5 random samples `[1]  1  4 13  7 11`, which you can reuse with Latex ...